# How to discover the function sigemptyset() to set value for sigset_t sa_mask

Tags: c, sigaction

I noticed that when a value has to be assigned to  `sigset_t sa_mask` 
and for example an empty value we can use the function
 `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask)`. I discovered it on StackOverflow. 
But when you look at the `man sigaction`, and `struct sigaction`
there is no mention of how are we going to assign value to `sa_mask`.
What I understand is for us it's of an unknown type so we cannot assume
it be anything and instead there should be some function that could
help us assign the value for type `sigset_t`. But the man page 
doesn't mention anything about functions like `sigemptyset`. 
How can one discover using man pages or some other tools that
you have to use some function like `sigemptyset` to initialize the 
sa_mask to be empty?

Comment: [sigemptyset()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sigemptyset) is just one of a family of APIs that let you clear, fill, add to and delete from a signal mask.  See also sigaddset(),  sigdelset(), sigfillset() and sigismember()

Comment: Which operating system's manpages are you looking at ? The answer may well be 'you should contact the author of the sigaction manpage and ask for it to be improved'

Comment: I have ubuntu WSL on windows 10

Comment: "WSL == Windows subsystem for Linux".  Ha ha ha :)  Most *real* *nix man pages will cross-reference "sigemptyset()" et al with "sigaction()".  For example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Comment: man7 page does list the sigemptyset at the end. Whereas my local manpage doesnt. But still I think it doesnt mention anywhere how are we supposed to assign a value to a type  **sigset_t**. Like there are other functions also in the family that allow to add delete signal mask. How do we discover them. Say I want to discover all APIs that deal with **sigset_t** type

Comment: The cross reference you want is to `sigsetops(3)`, but you're right, this probably should be clarified. I suggest contacting  linux-man@vger.kernel.org and telling them what you told us.